# how can i use normal UIViewcontroller as navigation controller?

Tags: iphone

I am using normal UIViewcontroller. But when i use pushviewcontroller in it, it is not working?
What i have to do ? Any help?

Comment: This question isn't clear. Navigation controller is a special type of viewcontroller that implements all the navigation stuff. If you are trying to use non-navigationcontroller as navigationcontroller, it won't work.

Comment: i asked to use like userdefined navigation controller in the normal UIView controller,if i add protocal,will it work?

Comment: A better explanation of what you are trying to do would be helpful. Why would you try to use a UIViewController as a navigation controller instead of just using UINavigationController? It's like trying to use a stick as a pencil when you have a pencil right there in front of you. I suspect you're just confused as to how the UINavigationController works. Look up the documentation on UINavigationController and read Apple's sample source code projects for some examples.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace your use of UIViewController with a UINavigationController.  UIViewController by does not support push/pop of view controllers.

Comment: No it will not, a protocol doesn't implement anything, it just specifies the methods you must implement.  There is not reason not to simply change your implementation to use a UINavigationController instead of a UIViewController.

Comment: What do you mean by a "user defined" navigation controller? Normally you use a standard navigation controller, customize the attributes of it, then configure it to use a specific UIViewController as it's default root controller. The UIViewController is displayed inside the navigation controller and can tell the navigation controller to push new view controllers by creating them and then calling self.navigationController.pushWhateverBlabla